# How to save data of the custom cell textfields?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

[image]

i am new to the iPhone development, i am developing an app were i have tableview with   custom-cell,my custom-cell contains label and textfiled. this is my registration screen,How to save the data of my textfields and,how to do validations for the text. In the textfield endediting we can save the data. but if the user on the first filed enter name and then he click done button it will show please enter first name, because i am saving data in didendediting. i want to save the data when ever user is on the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this method to trace your current textfield text, with the help of the model class objects to store your text.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *characterSet = nil; 
    switch (theTextField.tag) 
    {
        case 1:
            characterSet = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";
            [sharedInstance.registrationDetails setFirstName:theTextField.text];


            default:
            characterSet = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789?/!@#$&*.,-:; _";
            break;
    }
    NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:characterSet];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
    {
        unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) 
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the controller the delegate of the cell's textField and then implement these methods in your controller.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{    
    NSInteger tag = [textField tag];
if(tag == 0) {
//save first name text value
}
else if (tag == 1){
//save last name text value
}
else if etc....
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Just make sure you set the tag appropriately when you return the cell in

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You could also do some research on how to get the keyboard to act like a form handler with the next/previous buttons

Answer (score 0):

Register.h

```
@interface Register : NSObject {
    NSString *_firstNameTxt;
    NSString *_lastNameTxt;
NSString *_emailTxt;
    NSString *_passwordTxt;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * firstNameTxt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * lastNameTxt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * emailTxt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * passwordTxt;
@end
```

Register.m

```
@implementation Register
@synthesize firstNameTxt=_firstNameTxt;
@synthesize lastNameTxt =_lastNameTxt ;
@synthesize emailTxt=_emailTxt;
@synthesize passwordTxt= _passwordTxt;

- (void)dealloc{
[super dealloc];
 [_firstNameTxt release];
 [_lastNameTxt  release];
 [_emailTxt  release];
 [_passwordTxt  release];
 }
 @end
```

RegisterViewController.h

```
@class Register;

@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController {
    Register *objRegister;
}
```

RegisterViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
  objRegister = [[Register alloc] init];
}
```

tableview delegates

```
[txtFirstName setText:objRegister.firstNameTxt];
[txtLastName setText:objRegister.lastNameTxt];

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
// do the same code as Warren Burton Post

 }
```